# JW Player read from php

Tags: php, jwplayer

I'm totally new to PHP and JW player.

I have the following code that reads a video file in php and plays it as a video file in the browser:

**loadfile.php**

```
<?php
    header("pragma : no-cache");
    header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Content-Location: videos/testvid.mp4");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize("videos/testvid.mp4"));
    readfile("videos/testvid.mp4");
?>
```

JW player can play the video file by direct path as in here:

```
<div id="mediaplayer"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
                'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/jwplayer.swf',
                'file': 'videos/testvid.mp4',
                'id': 'playerID',
                'width': '480',
                'height': '320'
            });
        </script>
```

However, I need jw player to play the video in loadfile.php and not by direct path. In other words, I need to pass the video to JW player after streaming and reading it in php. How can I do this?

**Update:**

I'm using JW 6

Comment: and just changing the `file` URI to your loadfile.php endpoint doesn't work for you?

Comment: I've tried 'file': loadfile.php, but I've got nothing and the player disappears

Comment: @fareed What happens if you request `loadfile.php` directly (from your browser?) The video should start downloading or playing. If not, there is a problem in loadfile.php

Comment: accessing loadfile.php directly plays the file in the browser indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using JW6, here, under this line of code:

```
'id': 'playerID',
```

Add the following:

```
'type': 'mp4',
```

Now, the php file should work as the player's "file" variable, just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
clearstatcache();

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("videos/testvid.mp4"));
readfile("videos/testvid.mp4");
```

I'm having the same scenario (read video from php and play it with jwplayer) and this configuration works.

**JS**

On the client side, I embed jwPlayer as a SWFObject. Check if it's useful for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var so = new SWFObject('path/to/jplayer.swf','mpl',640,480,'9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('controlbar','over');
  so.addVariable('provider','video');
  so.addVariable('autostart','true');
  so.addVariable('file','loadfile.php');
  so.write('videoPlayer');  
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id='videoPlayer'></div>
</body>
```

Also try using absolute paths (just in case)...

Comment: Sorry, should be `so.addVariable('file','loadfile.php');`. Edited

Comment: any ideas why I can't play the video?

Comment: @fareed Sorry, no more ideas :( Consider opening a ticket with JW

Comment: Are you using JW Player 5 here or JW Player 6?

Comment: @Ethan I'm running jw 6 (OP)