# How to load mp3 into JW Player using php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, jwplayer

I'm trying to load an mp3 into JW Player 5 using php to retrieve the actual file. This is the javascript code for the player:

```
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
        'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
        'id': 'playerID',
        'type': 'mp3',
        'width': '600',
        'height': '49',
        'file': '/get_mp3/<?php echo $filename; ?>',
      });
```

The **file** attribute has the URL to the PHP function (I use **CakepHP**, the part after the last **/** is the variable that the function gets passed).

This is the PHP function:

```
function get_mp3($filename) {

    $file_path = '/path/to/files/' .$filename. '.mp3';

    header("pragma : no-cache");
    header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg3");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" .$filename. ".mp3");
    header("Content-Location: " .$filename. ".mp3");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file_path));
    readfile($file_path);
}
```

If I call that function via web browser (for example *mydomain.com/get_mp3/test_file*) it prompts to download the right file, which seems to show that the PHP code is working.

However, when I use it on JW PLayer's **file** attribute it doesn't load anything or shows any kind of error.

I've tried adapting what's shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994235/jw-player-read-from-php) SO question but I couldn't make it work, I don't know if it's because for video it's different or because that mentoins JW PLayer 6 and mine is 5.

**EDIT: test if it's an issue with CakePHP**

So test if the issue is that for some reason CakePHP isn't working with JW Player I've put the following PHP code in an external PHP file:

```
$filename= 'my_filename';

$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/path/to/files/' .$filename. '.mp3';

header("pragma : no-cache");
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: audio/x-mp3");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" .$filename. ".mp3");
header("Content-Location: " .$filename. ".mp3");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

So now, the `file` line in the JW Player declaration reads like:

```
'file': '/get_mp3.php',
```

With that it still doesn't work. If I access the **get_mp3.php** page directly I get prompted to download the file, so again looks like the PHP code works...

**EDIT 2**

SO I've found the culprit of the issue: the path of the audio file. If I put the file in the root folder of the website, and I use the file path variable like `$file_path = $filename. '.mp3';` it works fine.

The problem is that the audio files are in a different folder in the same server, and I can't move them... How can I change the PHP script to find the files in their current path? I've already tried with `$file = '/path/to/files/' .$filename. '.mp3';` and `$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/path/to/files/' .$filename. '.mp3';` but it doesn't work...

Comment: You're not using CakePHP at all in your code. You should use the response object.

Comment: @burzum could you expand on that? The website is all CakePHP, obviously here I'm just showing fragments. The javascript you see is in a view, and the PHP in a controller. What do you mean by using the **response** object? Could you give me an example?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html examples are included on that page.

Comment: @buzum dang it! I'm on cake 1.3, I should have mentioned that... I don't know if MediaView would an equivalent?

Comment: Yes, it was the old way to send files. Yes, *always* mention your *exact* CakePHP version.

Comment: @burzum Before going into messing with Cake I've tried using regualr PHP (see my edit in the question) and still doesn't work...

Comment: @burzum please see my edit 2, maybe you can help me with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out my problem was in the path to the file in the PHP script. I was using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and just `/` for the paths and it wasn't working, but then I realized that moving the file to the same folder as the script would work. In my case I still needed to find a way to access those files from a different folder, and using a **relative path** did the trick. Something like:

```
$filename= 'my_filename';

$file = '../../../path/to/files/' .$filename. '.mp3';

header("pragma : no-cache");
header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: audio/x-mp3");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=" .$filename. ".mp3");
header("Content-Location: " .$filename. ".mp3");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your content type to ("Content-Type: audio/x-mp3");

Comment: Tried another browser?

Comment: yep, tried in FF, Chrome, IE and Safari with same result in all of them

Comment: can u make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JW5.

Under:

```
'file': '/get_mp3/<?php echo $filename; ?>',
```

Add:

```
'provider': 'sound',
```

Comment: JW Player thank you for your response, I tried that with no difference at all. Please see my edit part in the question for what I've done. When I click "play" on the player the onPlay() event gets called, I've tested that, but nothing else happens...

Comment: I think something is wrong with the file 2.mp3 itself. I downloaded it and tried to play it locally using the JW Player and it still wouldn't play. It also would not play in any of my desktop media players, such as VLC, QuickTime, or Windows Media Player. I think that is the root cause here. Also the downloaded file is only 1 KB.

Comment: that's weird because if I load that same file directly into JW Player (without the php script) it plays fine... I'll see if I can find out what's going on, thanks!

Comment: I went to the php script directly, it popped a download box in my browser (firefox), and the downloaded file was only 1K, so maybe the script isn't pulling the whole file properly, then.

Comment: yep, the path to the file was incorrect, and absolute paths didn't work (see my answer). Thanks though!