# how to play mp4 video in jwplayer in php file

Tags: php, video, jwplayer

Hi any idea that how can i play dynamic mp4 video in jwplayer?
I want a sample code for running a mp4 vedio on a php page where i can give the video path dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who upvotes poorly asked questions

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994235/jw-player-read-from-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are JW 7 code examples (PHP and Python) here to take a look at:
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/developer-guide/

The answer referenced above uses JW 6, and those endpoints will no longer be supported after July 1 of this year.